# Error: Could not find or load main class during jar file execution in command prompt

Tags: java, jar, jdbc-odbc

I have written a java program in which I am creating a database connection using jdbc-odbc driver.

I have created manifest file which looks like :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.unisys.sql.CasePartitionExtractor
Class-Path: . rt.jar
```

rt.jar is used for database connectivity.

I ran following command to create jar:

```
jar -cvfm abc.jar manifest.txt \bin\com\unisys\sql\*.class \bin\com\unisys\connections\*.class
```

When I run the jar in command prompt, it's showing following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.unisys.sql.CasePartitionExtractor
```

Main Class is:              CasePartitionExtractor.java
Databse connection class:   ODBCConnection.java

Command used to run jar:

```
java -jar D:\Eclipse_OS2200\CaseSeparation\abc.jar
```

directory structure:

```
workspace->project_name->
                        bin/com/unisys/connections/ODBCConnection.class
                        bin/com/unisys/sql/CasePartitionExtractor.class
                        manifest.txt
                        rt.jar
```

I am not able to figure it out what is wrong in this. Can someone help me to figure it out?

Inside jar look:

[image: inside jar folder structure]

Comment: Can you verify that the class files are in the correct folder structure inside the jar?

Comment: How can I open jar to verify it?

Comment: use WinRar, 7Zip or any other compressor. Jar format is based on ZIP and the ZLIB compression format. Check you don't have the "bin" directory directly in your JAR file

Comment: no...there is no bin folder...com/ started and in main directory .classPath and .project exists. Added image for ref.

Comment: Your manifest is wrong too, ``manifest.txt`` will not have any effect. It should ne named ``MANIFEST.MF`` and be inside the folder ``META-INF``.

Comment: there is no META-INF folder??

Comment: Make also sure that the class `CasePartitionExtractor` has `main` method